# Xcode from App Store Stalling at About 11 Minutes Remaining

Tags: xcode, mac-appstore

I'm trying to install Xcode from the App Store onto a Mac mini (the vast majority of my experience with PCs involves Windows and Linux). I've tried three times, and each time it stalls out at around 11 minutes remaining.

What could be causing this problem? This is a refurbished Mac mini, with the latest version of Sierra installed, and very little else.

Is there another way to download and install the software?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Xcode install takes an unusually long time even on a modern system, and the time estimates are often inaccurate. Just leave it be for a while -- it may take as long as a few hours.

Installing an SSD in the Mini will help significantly.

Comment: Thanx! It eventually did finish installing, but you're right, the time estimate towards the end -- the last 10 minutes or so -- were wildly off. And that's on a system that has an SSD.

Comment: Agreed. As of Xcode 11.1, it is a 7.64Gb download. The install itself took absolutely ages and appeared to hang in places. However it did eventually succeed. Roughly time taken about forty minutes from download completion. That was MacBook Pro 2018 with SSD.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it could be the drive as well. Examine for errors and perhaps use drive recovery software to rebuild it. DiskWarrior or SpinRite for example. More than likely should update the drive regardless.